# HTML table leaving open gaps when hiding cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

The example below contains two tables, and each table includes two sections.  Both tables and sections are structurally the same.

When the cells in the first table that are marked with class ".to-hide" are hidden by changing this class to ".hide" (shown in the second table), the resulting layout of the second table appears inconsistent; the cell "4" in the first section closes all gaps left by the hidden cells, but cell "4" in the second section leaves open gaps.

On Chrome 68.0.3440.106, the code snippet below shows how one cell "4" fill open gaps, but the other cell "4" does not.  On Firefox 60.0.2, both cells "4" leave open gaps.  The image below is taken on Chrome 68.

[image: Table with hidden cells leaving gaps on Chrome]
How can I ensure that visible cells in the table cover any gaps left by hidden cells, consistently, across browsers?

```css
/* Styles to mark and hide marked cells. */
.to-hide { background-color: lightgray; }
.hide { display: none; }

/* Styles to make the tables in the code snippet look pretty. */
.left { display: inline-block; }
.right { display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; }
table { background-color: yellow; }
td { padding: 0 1em; background-color: white; border: solid 1px gray; }
```

```html
<div class="left">
Original table:

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">.<br/>2<br/>.</td>
      <td class="to-hide">3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="to-hide">a</td>
      <td class="to-hide">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">i</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">.<br/>2<br/>.</td>
      <td class="to-hide">3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="to-hide">a</td>
      <td class="to-hide">b</td>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">i</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
<div class="right">
Shaded cells hidden (notice cells "4"):

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">.<br/>2<br/>.</td>
      <td class="hide">3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide">a</td>
      <td class="hide">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">i</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">.<br/>2<br/>.</td>
      <td class="hide">3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide">a</td>
      <td class="hide">b</td>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">i</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Running on Safari 11.1.2, both tables exhibit the same behavior when I run your code snippet. Firefox 61.0.2 renders cell 4 differently than Safari but is still consistent between both tables. To clarify, the image your have provided has two tables - the former matches with Safari and the latter matches with Firefox.

Comment: I'm running it on Chrome 68.0.3440.106.  I added a link to the image showing what I see.

Comment: Confirming that Chrome behaves as you state it does and that Chrome behaves differently from Safari and Firefox. 
As your code is behaving differently across three different browsers, I will suggest looking for a different approach.

Comment: You have a col-span of '3' on the 'A' cell, if you bump that down to '2' and change the colspan on 'i' down from '4' to '3', it seems to correct the problem you're seeing. I'm not sure why it affects it in that way, but it seems like the issue is likely due to those col-spans.

Comment: As suggested, one workaround was to change the underlying structure of the table by changing the rowspan and colspan when a cell is hidden.  This requires some javascript.  The simpler solution I finally implemented is to simply wrap the content of the table cells and hide those:  Instead of <td class="hide">blah</td>, I did this <td><div class="hide">blah</div></td>.  This keeps the structure of the <table> intact, and as long as it is styled to collapse borders and margins on all <td>s, the result meets the requirements.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

By hiding cells "a" and "b" `rowspan="3"` of cell "1" wants to occupy the same area like cell "i". Cell "i" can not span 3 rows since there are only 3 rows left and on the last row spans cell "i" all columns.

Forcing hidden cells to a size of 0 does not help.

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Taking hidden cells out of flow by `position: absolute` does not help either.

That the first section of the table still looks good (no gaps) must be some kind of error correction by browser.

Only by removing hidden cells from the table and changing the values for `rowspan` and `colspan` I was able to achieve the intended distribution of cells.

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">1</td>
  <td>.<br/>2<br/>.</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">i</td>
</tr>
```